# New values to the vector of const char* is not getting push_back()

Tags: c++

I have a vector of cons char* . Which is actually a timestamp . Every time , i am fetching the last value , converting it to integer , increment by 40 . And then pushing it back to vector as const char* . My problem is , new values are not getting push_back(). Vector already contains some value .

I have tried to create instances instead of doing it directly like
Instead of this

```
string is = to_string(y);
some_vector.push_back(is.c_str());
```

I am doing

```
string is = to_string(y);
const char * temp = is.c_str();
some_vector.push_back(temp);
```

My full code is

```
vector<const char *> TimeConstraint; 
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        const char * tx = TimeConstraint.back();

        int y;
        stringstream strval;

        strval << tx;
        strval >> y;

        y = y + 40;

        string is = to_string(y);
        const char* temp_pointer = is.c_str();
        TimeConstraint.push_back(temp_pointer);


    }
```

New values are not getting added to TimeConstraint vector

Every time i have to push_back() the incremented value of the last element of the vector.Please help me 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This:

```
    string is = to_string(y);
    const char* temp_pointer = is.c_str();
    TimeConstraint.push_back(temp_pointer);
```

Is trouble.
The pointer returned by `is.c_str()` is only valid as long as `is` is alive, which it only is until the next iteration of the loop.

I would suggest you change `TimeConstraint` to hold `std::string` objects instead and then do:

```
    TimeConstraint.push_back(is);
```

then your container keeps the string alive as long as needed.

Another problem is

```
const char * tx = TimeConstraint.back();
```

Since it is not valid to call `.back()` on an empty `std::vector`. That code causes Undefined Behaviour and renders your program meaningless. The compiler has *no obligation* to do anything sensible any more.

Comment: Thank you Jesper . I will use vector<string> TimeConstraint .

Comment: @AdityaNadig If this was helpful, you could accept the answer as well.